# Find and replace domain address in xml file

Tags: xml, powershell

I am looking for assistance with a script or piece of code to add to an existing script which will look up the domain portion of a user SIP address and replace it with a new domain.

The exiting script changes the main user address which works fine, but I need an additional part which will lookup any addresses in the xml file matching `@domainA.com` and *replace* it with `@domainB.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to use a *regex* replace:

```
(Get-Content C:\imports\$username\DocItemSet.xml -raw) -replace '@domainB\.com', '@domainA.com' |
     Set-Content C:\imports\$username\DocItemSet.xml
```

**Note:** You probably want to specify the `-Encoding` parameter within the `Set-Content` cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks, shortly after posting the question I found a similar post and response which seems to working.

$Content = Get-Content "C:\imports\$username\DocItemSet.xml" | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace $A, $B} | Set-Content $path\$username\DocItemSetTest.xml